# How to test .xap file LG Quantum C900 Unlocked Windows Phone directly?

Tags: windows-phone-7

We are having  LG Quantum C900 Unlocked Windows Phone.
Then can we directly test the .xap file in that device without apphub account?

We installed zune software and windows phone SDK while testing we got below error:

"Device screen is unlocked like that error message i got."

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error? Is Zune running? Is the phone recognized in Zune? Have you unlocked your phone from the pinlock?

Comment: Yes Phone is Recognised in Zune but we are not having developer account?can u please tell unlocked device means?

Answer (score 2):

As far as im aware you need a app hub developer account to unlock your device.

EDIT: There is a tool that comes with the wp7 tools called Windows Phone Developer Registration. This allows you to unlock your phone so that you can deploy apps directly to it, you must have an app hub account to use it though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few kinds of "unlocked" device.

1) A "normal" device whose screen is not locked and is capable of user input.
2) A "developer unlocked" device - i.e. one that a registered developer (with an app hub account) has unlocked to allow testing software on the hardware.
3) SIM unlocked (a device that can take a SIM card from any network and is not tied down to a single operator)

It is an important distinction.  It sounds like "unlocked" in your context is the first one, whereas you need the second in order to deploy XAP files to the device.

If you wish to test software on the device, you can either sign up to app hub yourself, at which point you can unlock (I think) 4 devices for testing, or if you know someone with an app hub account who is willing to help you out, you can have them developer unlock the device for you.

My personal choice would be to pay the 99 bucks and join app hub, if for no other reason than that route will allow you to put your app on the Marketplace once it is finished.  There is no other (legitimate) way to distribute the software to end users.

Answer (score 0):

[ChevronWP7](http://www.chevronwp7.com/) is an officially supported alternative for unlocking your phone and costs $9 USD per phone, but does not allow you to publish applications (you'll need a separate Marketplace account for that).

Alternatively, there is an [unsupported method of unlocking](http://www.haroldchia.com/2011/03/how-to-developer-unlock-wp7-without.html) that only works on LG phones (as LG's dev menu contains a registry editor... oops!)